# Avoiding Out of Memory Error with Bitmap Factory, Even When Resizing Isn't an Issue?

Tags: android, bitmap, window, out-of-memory, bitmapfactory

I've researched at least 10 similar topics on SO, however, none have reached a definitive answer for me allowing me to avoid the Out of Memory error Bitmaps are known for.

Taking into consideration the advice from these previous questions, I constructed the following method `setBipmapFromPath` to produce an optimally sized (both in dimensions and kilobytes) wallpaper image from a file path. This method works fine on a large RAM device like my G2, however, it crashes in an emulator with 1.5GB of RAM using a 256kb picture.

I welcome any criticism that will help me prevent the Out of Memory error. My hope is to also ensure the image can still act as a proper background image, as in, fill the screen of the device reasonably without insane stretch marks.

My methods:

```
public void recycleWallpaperBitmap() {
    if (mBitmap != null) {

        mBitmap.recycle();
        mBitmap = null;
    }
}

 private void setBitmapFromPath() {

    // Recycle the bitmap just in case.
    recycleWallpaperBitmap();

    String path = mProfileManager.getWallpaperPath();

    if (path != null) {

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

        int displayWidth = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
        int displayHeight = display.getHeight();  // deprecated

        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        mBitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options),
                displayWidth, displayHeight);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This method works fine on a large RAM device like my G2, however, it crashes in an emulator with 1.5GB of RAM using a 256kb picture.

It will fail on the G2 as well, depending on where and when you call this method. Your "256kb" picture will take up several MB of heap space, and there is no assurance that you have that amount of heap space available in a single contiguous block.

Also, I would not use a class and method designed for creating thumbnails will be suitable for creating wallpaper-sized images.

> I welcome any criticism that will help me prevent the Out of Memory error.

Use `inSampleSize` on your `BitmapFactory.Options` to downsample the image to closer to the right size while it is being read in.

Then, dump your use of `ThumbnailUtils` and allow your `ImageView` to scale it the rest of the way, to avoid making yet another copy of the image.

Bonus points for using `inBitmap` instead of junking and re-allocating your `Bitmap` every time, since the screen size is not changing, and therefore your wallpaper dimensions are not changing.

These techniques and more are covered in [the developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html).

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, thank you for the reply! I was using inSampleSize, however, if the image isn't > 2x as large as the screen, I can't use inSampleSize to make it smaller given the constraints of needing a power of 2. I was using the exact code in the documentation, though it had no effect on the size of the image given my screen is 1080p and the image was not 2x 1080p. Heck, I wonder, even if it scales it down to 1080p, what guarantee do I have it won't be too large then? 
Thank you!

Comment: @AutoM8R: You can try allocating space for the `Bitmap` up front, when your process starts, and keep using the same `Bitmap` for every `decodeFile()` request, using `inBitmap` on `BitmapFactory.Options`. That, plus allowing the `ImageView` to do the scaling for you, should allow you to load the image more reliably.

Comment: I am targeting version 8, so I am unable to use inBitmap, but I have successfully scaled the image using the ImageView, and I utilized the following code to manage memory: https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html for 2.3.3. Thank you!